# Many repository errors when I update && upgrade

Tags: package-management

```
sudo apt-get clean                           
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
Hit:1 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/embrosyn/cinnamon/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Get:3 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian zesty InRelease [7,774 B]
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty InRelease      
Ign:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease        
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release          
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Ign:9 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease [89.2 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease [89.2 kB]
Hit:12 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease 
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:14 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release
Hit:15 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease               
Ign:3 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian zesty InRelease
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:17 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x yakkety InRelease        
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty Release  
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Hit:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease          
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease [89.2 kB]
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages                                                             
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                                           
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                                                         
Ign:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                                                       
Ign:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                                                          
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages                                                                                                                                
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                              
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages                                                                                                                               
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en                                                                                                                              
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                                           
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                                                         
Ign:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                                                       
Ign:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                                                          
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages                                                                                                                                
Err:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                              
  404  Not Found                                                                                                                                                                                            
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages                                                                                                                               
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en                                                                                                                              
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                                           
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                                                         
Ign:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                                                       
Ign:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                                                          
Fetched 275 kB in 3s (70.7 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                            
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                               
W: GPG error: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian zesty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF           
W: The repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian zesty InRelease' is not signed.                                                                                                         
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.                                                                                                        
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.                                                                                                                        
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'edge/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'                             
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.                                                                                               
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.                                                                                                        
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I have this sources list

```
    # 

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412)]/ zesty main restricted

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412)]/ zesty main restricted

# See URL://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

# deb-src URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted
# deb-src URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe
# deb-src URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe
deb URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates universe
# deb-src URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse
# deb-src URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse
deb URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates multiverse
# deb-src URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb URL://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner
# deb-src URL://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner

deb URL://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security main restricted
# deb-src URL://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security main restricted
deb URL://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security universe
# deb-src URL://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security universe
deb URL://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security multiverse
# deb-src URL://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] URLs://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] URLs://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty stable
deb [arch=armhf] URLs://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty stable
# deb-src [arch=armhf] URLs://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty stable
# deb [arch=amd64] URLs://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable

# deb URLs://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-zesty testing
# deb-src URLs://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-zesty testing
# deb URL://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi

deb URL://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian zesty contrib
```

I don't have any links with 1386.

Also here are my sеttings:

[image: software sources]

[image: updates settings]

[image: Other Software]

`sources.list.d` has these:

```
➜  sources.list.d ls         
docker.list                                  nodesource.list.save
docker.list.save                             papirus-ubuntu-papirus-zesty.list
embrosyn-ubuntu-cinnamon-zesty.list          papirus-ubuntu-papirus-zesty.list.save
embrosyn-ubuntu-cinnamon-zesty.list.save     spotify.list
google-chrome.list                           spotify.list.save
google-chrome.list.save                      steam.list
graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-zesty.list       steam.list.save
graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-zesty.list.save  vscode.list
mongodb-org-3.2.list                         vscode.list.save
mongodb-org-3.2.list.save                    webupd8team-ubuntu-java-zesty.list
nodesource.list                              webupd8team-ubuntu-java-zesty.list.save
```

**UPDATED**:

```
➜ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease
Ign:2 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease                                            
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/embrosyn/cinnamon/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                              
Hit:4 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                                                       
Hit:5 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release                                                                    
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                           
Ign:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                   
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu zesty InRelease                          
Hit:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                     
Hit:10 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x yakkety InRelease             
Hit:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease               
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu zesty InRelease  
Hit:13 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease [89.2 kB]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease [89.2 kB]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/multiverse amd64 Packages [154 kB]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/multiverse i386 Packages [147 kB]
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/multiverse Translation-en [109 kB]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [43.3 kB]
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [207 kB]
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main Sources [26.8 kB]
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 Packages [78.3 kB]
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main i386 Packages [76.7 kB]
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main Translation-en [35.5 kB]
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,812 B]
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [8,900 B]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [27.0 kB]
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [41.9 kB]
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [57.6 kB]
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [58.7 kB]
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [4,176 B]
Get:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [4,320 B]
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/multiverse Translation-en [2,168 B]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [2,638 B]
0% [Working]^C
```

it gets stuck here now :(

```
➜  sources.list.d ls
docker.list                               google-chrome.list.save                      nodesource.list                         spotify.list.save  webupd8team-ubuntu-java-zesty.list
docker.list.save                          graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-zesty.list       nodesource.list.save                    steam.list         webupd8team-ubuntu-java-zesty.list.save
embrosyn-ubuntu-cinnamon-zesty.list       graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-zesty.list.save  papirus-ubuntu-papirus-zesty.list       steam.list.save
embrosyn-ubuntu-cinnamon-zesty.list.save  mongodb-org-3.2.list                         papirus-ubuntu-papirus-zesty.list.save  vscode.list
google-chrome.list                        mongodb-org-3.2.list.save                    spotify.list                            vscode.list.save
```

This is my `sources.list`

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted universe 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted universe 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-security main restricted universe 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted universe 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-security main restricted universe 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted universe 

## Ubuntu Sources
deb URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted universe multiverse
deb URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb URL://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

After the last fix

```
➜  ~ sudo apt update
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease [89.2 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease [89.2 kB]
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease [243 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/restricted Sources [956 B]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main Sources [28.2 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe Sources [11.5 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main i386 Packages [80.3 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 Packages [82.2 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main Translation-en [37.5 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,816 B]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [5,289 B]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [2,168 B]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/restricted i386 Packages [2,156 B]
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/restricted Translation-en [1,280 B]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [192 B]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe amd64 Packages [39.8 kB]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe i386 Packages [39.9 kB]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe Translation-en [25.9 kB]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [8,900 B]
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [27.0 kB]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main Sources [49.9 kB]
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/restricted Sources [956 B]
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe Sources [20.0 kB]
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 Packages [124 kB]
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main i386 Packages [122 kB]
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main Translation-en [56.6 kB]
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [41.8 kB]
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [14.0 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [2,168 B]
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [2,156 B]
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/restricted Translation-en [1,280 B]
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [193 B]
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [68.6 kB]
Get:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe i386 Packages [68.5 kB]
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe Translation-en [39.0 kB]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [57.6 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [63.5 kB]
Get:38 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe Sources [8,459 kB]
Get:39 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/restricted Sources [5,064 B]
Get:40 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main Sources [912 kB]
Get:41 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages [1,207 kB]
Get:42 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages [1,204 kB]
Get:43 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en [577 kB]
Get:44 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [536 kB]
Get:45 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [373 kB]
Get:46 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/restricted i386 Packages [8,648 B]
Get:47 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/restricted amd64 Packages [8,672 B]
Get:48 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/restricted Translation-en [2,724 B]
Get:49 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [185 B]
Get:50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 Packages [8,068 kB]
Get:51 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe i386 Packages [8,037 kB]
Get:52 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe Translation-en [4,671 kB]
Get:53 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,713 kB]
Get:54 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7,842 kB]
Fetched 421 kB in 8s (49.7 kB/s)                                                                                                
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
16 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
➜  ~ sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
libc-bin/zesty-security,zesty-updates 2.24-9ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.24-9ubuntu2]
libc-dev-bin/zesty-security,zesty-updates 2.24-9ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.24-9ubuntu2]
libc6/zesty-security,zesty-updates 2.24-9ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.24-9ubuntu2]
libc6-dbg/zesty-security,zesty-updates 2.24-9ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.24-9ubuntu2]
libc6-dev/zesty-security,zesty-updates 2.24-9ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.24-9ubuntu2]
libc6-i386/zesty-security,zesty-updates 2.24-9ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.24-9ubuntu2]
libclick-0.4-0/zesty-updates 0.4.46+17.04.20170607.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.4.45.1+16.10.20160916-0ubuntu1]
linux-headers-generic/zesty-security,zesty-updates 4.10.0.24.26 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.10.0.22.24]
linux-image-extra-virtual/zesty-security,zesty-updates 4.10.0.24.26 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.10.0.22.24]
linux-image-generic/zesty-security,zesty-updates 4.10.0.24.26 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.10.0.22.24]
linux-libc-dev/zesty-security,zesty-updates 4.10.0-24.28 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.10.0-22.24]
linux-signed-generic/zesty-security,zesty-updates 4.10.0.24.26 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.10.0.22.24]
linux-signed-image-generic/zesty-security,zesty-updates 4.10.0.24.26 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.10.0.22.24]
locales/zesty-security,zesty-security,zesty-updates,zesty-updates 2.24-9ubuntu2.2 all [upgradable from: 2.24-9ubuntu2]
multiarch-support/zesty-security,zesty-updates 2.24-9ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.24-9ubuntu2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean up your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and move none distribution sources to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

```
## Ubuntu Sources
deb URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted universe multiverse
deb URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb URL://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb URL://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security main restricted universe multiverse

## move to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
deb [arch=amd64] URLs://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty stable
## The armhf is very strange... it will not work on your amd64!
deb [arch=armhf] URLs://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty stable

## move to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
deb URL://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian zesty contrib
```

Also add the proper key for the virtualbox sources as descriped here https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads:

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

And there are some other sources inside the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder that you need to fix.

### Update

Move the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` into a Backup location, clean `/var/lib/apt/lists/` and run `apt update` again.

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d /etc/apt/sources.list.d_backup
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt update
```

If that process is successful, start copying one file after another from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d_backup`, until the error happens again. Than you found the reason for your problem.

Comment: i edited my question, added bottom. sources.d only have those

➜  sources.list.d ls and why have to fix each one, why not automatically do those?

Comment: look inside the differnt files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. In every file is a deb... somehting line. Some entries are double, remove them. Also the `arch=XXX` line is not needed for your host system. Remove it, if you don't know way it is there.

Comment: @vegan can you update the output of `sudo apt update`?

Comment: this time it stucked at `get:64 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/multiverse DEP-11 ` :(

Comment: i changed to old soıurces and then it worked.  `Fetched 421 kB in 8s (49.7 kB/s)                                                                                                
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
16 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
➜  ~ sudo apt list --upgradable
` i also added to question

Comment: and still nosources.d. what should i do, use backup? ,apt.conf.d     preferences.d  sources.list~      ss.d         trusted.gpg~
apt-file.conf  sources.list   sources.list.save  trusted.gpg  trusted.gpg.d
` ss.d is my backup

Comment: i used backup but this time again  `Get:40 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise/steam amd64 Packages [601 B]
Fetched 188 kB in 2s (76.6 kB/s) 
Reading package lists... Done
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/URLs could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-URLs installed?
E: Failed to fetch URLs://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/zesty/InRelease  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
`

Comment: i fixed. you put URLs. iti s wrong. i put because i cantput links.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also imported the keys of each repo. Especially the https:// ones. A simpler way might be to make a valid sources.list file tailor made for your system based on the system's version and the GEO-IP proximity of your system to the closest repo. You can generate a repo on `https://repogen.simplylinux.ch` and save it onto /etc/apt/sources.list also since this service was intended to generate deb links to the more ubiquitous repos, you will have to add the less common PPAs individually.