# Can't update properly on Ubuntu 16.04 using sudo apt-get update. Also cannot install pgadmin3 or oracle-java-8. Says you have held broken packages

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, java

I get the following message(tail) when using the command `sudo apt-get update`

```
Fetched 280 kB in 6min 15s (744 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian sid InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553  NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
W: The repository 'http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian sid InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://mirrors.linsrv.net/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian wheezy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linsrv.net/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'mirrors.linsrv.net:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Also, it takes too much time at the following repo:

```
http://mirrors.linsrv.net/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian wheezy/main
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/926993/17-04-update-upgrade-error. Its not the same, but it should help you solve your problem

Comment: Mixing Ubuntu and Debian repos is unwise, and will surely break your system in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least for the first warning, the solution is to add/renovate the new GPG keys with the following command:

> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8B48AD6246925553
>
> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7638D0442B90D010

And for the error in the mariadb, that repository is old; you need to remove the old repository. Add the new GPG key and the new repository address (https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=tedeco&distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=xenial--ubuntu_xenial&version=10.2):

> sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:http://mirrors.linsrv.net/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>
> sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8
>
> sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386,ppc64el] http://tedeco.fi.upm.es/mirror/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu xenial main'